# Android: populating Linear Layout programmatically, It gets extra space

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I'm trying to populate a `LinearLayout` horizontally with some `ImageViews` programmatically. In horizontal directon, everything works very well, but it reserves extra space vertically what I don't want.

Here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="es.uam.dadm.jacopo_grassi_connecta4.Settings" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/your_color" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/your_color_container" >

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/adv_color" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/adv_color_container" >

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sounds" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/sounds_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's the java code:

```
private PlayerDataSource playersdb;
private Player player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    playersdb = new PlayerDataSource(this);
    player = playersdb.getPlayer(extras.getString(Utils.PARAM_PLAYER_ID));

    buildColors();

    Switch sounds = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.sounds_switch);
    sounds.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    sounds.setChecked(player.getSounds() == 0 ? false : true);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Integer tag = (Integer) v.getTag(R.id.TAG_ADV);
    if(tag == null){        //your color
        tag = (Integer) v.getTag(R.id.TAG_YOU);
        player.setColor(tag);
    }else{                  //adv color
        player.setColorAdv(tag);
    }
    playersdb.updatePlayer(player);
    buildColors();
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked){
        player.setSounds(1);
    }else{
        player.setSounds(0);
    }
    playersdb.updatePlayer(player);
}

private void buildColors(){
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_color_container);
    parent.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.weight = 0.2f;
        ImageView v = new ImageView(this);
        Integer drawable = null;
        switch (i){
        case 0:
            drawable = R.drawable.red_piece;
            break;
        case 1:
            drawable = R.drawable.yellow_piece;
            break;
        case 2:
            drawable = R.drawable.green_piece;
            break;
        case 3:
            drawable = R.drawable.purple_piece;
            break;
        case 4:
            drawable = R.drawable.azure_piece;
            break;
        }
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        v.setImageResource(drawable);
        v.setTag(R.id.TAG_YOU, drawable);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (drawable.equals(player.getColor())) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.azul));
        }

        parent.addView(v);
    }

    parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adv_color_container);
    parent.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.weight = 0.2f;
        ImageView v = new ImageView(this);
        Integer drawable = null;
        switch (i){
        case 0:
            drawable = R.drawable.red_piece;
            break;
        case 1:
            drawable = R.drawable.yellow_piece;
            break;
        case 2:
            drawable = R.drawable.green_piece;
            break;
        case 3:
            drawable = R.drawable.purple_piece;
            break;
        case 4:
            drawable = R.drawable.azure_piece;
            break;
        }
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        v.setImageResource(drawable);
        v.setTag(R.id.TAG_ADV, drawable);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (drawable.equals(player.getColorAdv())) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.azul));
        }

        parent.addView(v);
    }
}
```

and that's the result:

[image: result]

Obviously, the images are perfect squares.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried layout parameters LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT instead of LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT?

Comment: Check again may your images are not perfectly square. Check original .png images' pixel, make sure they have same height in px as width in px.

Comment: no, they're. 150x150

Comment: I think the problem is with your images, all your images might be perfect squares but they may not be of the same size, please make sure that all the images above, (red_piece, yellow_piece, green_piece, purple_piece, azure_piece) are all of 150x150 pixels, if any is larger then that's what causing the gap

Comment: no, all of them are 150x150

Comment: Just a hunch, try setting adjustViewBounds = true on your imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to @Terence 
Added

```
v.setAdjustViewBounds = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change the android:layout_height of your *outer* LinearLayout to "wrap_content"?

Comment: the outer it's already on `wrap_content`:

`<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/your_color_container" >`

Comment: That's the inner one. I said the *OUTER* one.

Comment: oh, sorry. yes it's the same

Comment: I set up a project with your code and I cannot reproduce the issue. It must be related to something not shown in your question. Please post the code where you inflate your layout etc, and if applicable, any other layout that the posted layout is embedded into, etc.

Comment: I included all your code (except I changed the images since I don't have yours) and it works as expected, the layout around the images wrap them closely. I am not sure why you see different results, it must still be related to something outside of what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your LinearLayout.Params width & height to "LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT" & also height of linear layout in XML file

Answer (score 0):

Try  `parent.addView(v, params);`

Comment: I wasn't critiquing, I was offering a solution. Adding the params argument to the addView method should offer the desired output of wrapping content

Answer (score 0):

This is how to solve your problem.

(the below code should be added into your for loop before parent.addView(v)

You need to use a Runnable thread in order to get the Views width which will be set as the height at runtime or else you'll be trying to set the Height before you know the View's width because the layout hasn't been drawn yet.

```
v.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mParams;
        mParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        mParams.height = v.getWidth();
        v.setLayoutParams(mParams);
        v.postInvalidate();
    }
});
```

v.postInvalidate() is called to force the view to redraw while on a separate thread than the UI thread